# Autocomplete in jQuery Search form doesn't accept apostrophe character

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, autocomplete

I am using jQuery Autocomplete with a search box on a website using Wordpress. The search box works fine and displays products when there is no single quote. But when there is a single quote I it displays no products. The single quote appears in "Women's Product Model and Number".

I have tried:  Women"'"s Shoe Product, Women\'s, Women/'s, Women\'s, within the search box and neither have worked. Some options will give no results others will list all of the Womens products.

Below is the code for the search page:

```
<?php include('inc/page-header.php'); ?>

<?php if (!have_posts()){ ?>
    <?php include('inc/no-results.php'); ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php
    $term_args = array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'hide_empty' => false
    );
    foreach(get_terms('footwear-categories', $term_args) as $cat){
        $results = 0;
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2><?php echo $cat->name; ?> <span class="badge <?php echo "results-".$cat->slug; ?>"></span></h2>
            </div>
            <?php
            while(have_posts()){
                the_post();
                $current_cat = get_field('main_category');
                if($current_cat && $current_cat[0]->slug == $cat->slug){
                    $results ++;
                    include('inc/list-product.php');
                }
            }
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function(){
                    jQuery('.<?php echo "results-".$cat->slug; ?>').html('<?php echo $results; ?>');
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

?>
```

Below is the code for auto complete:

```
// Auto complete search...
jQuery('.search-field').autocomplete({
  source: jQuery.parseJSON(styles),
  select: function(event, ui){
    jQuery(event.target).val('"'+ui.item.value+'"');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Below is the code for the search box:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form form-inline" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" value="<?php if (is_search()) { echo get_search_query(); } ?>" name="s" class="search-field form-control" placeholder="<?php _e('Search', 'roots'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
        <label class="hide"><?php _e('Search for:', 'roots'); ?></label>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="search-submit btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your php code?

Comment: Odds are that the single quote is being treated as the end of a string in a SQL database on the backend.  I recommend replacing the single quotes with two single quotes.

Comment: I have updated my post.